# xslt for 'n' repeated elements create 'n' output

Tags: xslt

Please, any of your thoughts that you might think of as a solution will help.   I've been asked to come up with xslt style-sheet which dynamically creates n repeated elements for n repeated element as an input. For instance, under the parent element A, there are many children element with different values but I only have to extract values of Element1, Element2,...*n*Elements and wanted to get the results *n*Result.

```
<input>
    <A>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
        <Element3>Value3</Element3>
        .... n number of elements
        <name>name</name>
        <ID>idmumber</ID>
        <address>address</address>
    </A>
    <B>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
        <!--....n number of elements-->
        <name>name</name>
        <ID>idmumber</ID>
        <address>address</address>
    </B>
</input>



<output>
    <X>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="/input/A/Element1"/>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="/input/A/Element2"/>
        </Result>
        <Result>
            <xsl:value-of select="/input/A/Element3"/>
        </Result>
        <!--....n number of elements-->
    </X>
    <Y>
        <Element1>
            <xsl:value-of select="/input/B/Element1"/>
        </Element1>
        <Element2>
            <xsl:value-of select="/input/B/Element2"/>
        </Element2>
        <!--....n number of elements-->
    </Y>
</output>
```

Comment: Can you show the output you expect in this case? Is it just the elements named "Element..." you want in the output, or will "name", "ID" and "address" be needed too? Thanks!

Comment: I only need the elements named "Element" in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This where you could benefit from a more template approach. For example, to change an `input` element into an `output` element, you would have the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="input">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

But you don't want lots of templates for changing the name of the `Element` elements. For those, you need some extra conditional checks....

```
<xsl:template match="input/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'Element')]">
    <Result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>
```

You would have a similar template to remove the non-Element elements.

```
<xsl:template match="input/*/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'Element'))]" />
```

This would avoid hard-coding `name`, `ID` and `address`.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="input">
        <output>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <X>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </X>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="B">
        <Y>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Y>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="input/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'Element')]">
        <Result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="input/*/*[not(starts-with(name(), 'Element'))]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you could slightly simplify this, and remove the duplicate check on the element name, by using template priorities. Try replacing the last two templates with these instead...

```
<xsl:template match="input/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'Element')]" priority="2">
    <Result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="input/*/*" />
```

Comment: Sune and Tim, I really appriciate. Thank you so much. Working perfectly!.

Comment: @Abdulkadir: Please [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

XSLT-Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
 <xsl:template match="input">
  <output>
    <xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:apply-templates>      
  </output>    
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="input/*">
   <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:element>      
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="input/*/*">
    <xsl:if test="contains(name(),'Element')">
    <xsl:element name="Result">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
    </xsl:element>


    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML Sample (yours):

```
<input>
    <A>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
        <Element3>Value3</Element3>
        <name>name</name>
        <ID>idmumber</ID>
        <address>address</address>
    </A>
    <B>
        <Element1>Value1</Element1>
        <Element2>Value2</Element2>
        <name>name</name>
        <ID>idmumber</ID>
        <address>address</address>
    </B>
</input>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><output>
    <A>
        <Result>Value1</Result>
        <Result>Value2</Result>
        <Result>Value3</Result>



    </A>
    <B>
        <Result>Value1</Result>
        <Result>Value2</Result>



    </B>
</output>
```